# Jumbling the data within the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario, where i have to mask the data with data within the table
let's say I have a table `student_details(ID, CODE, NAME)`

```
1   A  XYZ
2   A  123
3   A  QWERTY
```

I want the output as

```
1   A  QWERTY
2   A   XYZ
3   A   123
```

I want the name to be within the name list in that table
for same id I Want different name which is in the table.

`select * from emp_details order by dbms_random.value;`
is giving some random names which are not in list.

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: In your example, there are no rows with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option: recalculate the `ID` value using `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function which orders rows by the hash value over concatenated `name`, `code` and `id` columns (that's just for example; you can pick something different).

```
SQL> with test (id, code, name) as
  2    (select 1, 'A', 'XYZ'    from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'A', '123'    from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'A', 'QUERTY' from dual
  5    ),
  6  inter as
  7    (select row_number() over (order by ora_hash(name || code || id)) id,
  8            code, name
  9     from test
 10    )
 11  select t.id, t.code, i.name
 12  from test t join inter i on t.id = i.id;

        ID C NAME
---------- - ------
         1 A XYZ
         2 A QUERTY
         3 A 123

SQL>
```

Comment: But in my case i have millions of records

Comment: Hi,Can't we use dbms_random?

Comment: As far as I understood, you said you want to *shuffle* values in that table. Sorting won't do that (if applied to the same table) as you'd get *rows* sorted, but each row would be just the same as the original one, no difference. DBMS_RANDOM? I don't know whether you can use it or not. If I had to put a bet, I'd say *yes, you can*, but how - that's another question.

Comment: @Prince - seems like you need to **edit your question** and explain your exact scenario in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to **permutate** selected columns in your table and leave the rest of the table unchanged, you may use a join with a *key permutation* table.

Assume your data as follows:

```
        ID CODE NAME 
---------- ---- ------
      1001 A    XYZ    
      1002 B    123    
      1004 C    QUERTY 
      1005 A    FOO
```

Note, that the `PK` is *not continuous*, wich is the generall case. If you have the PK a continuous sequence starting with 1, you may even simplify the solution (as proposed in other answer).

First lets define the **permutation table** assigning to each `PK` a new key in random order.

```
create table PERM as
with rn as (
select 
  id,
  row_number() over (order by id) rn,
  row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) rn_new
from student)
select a.ID, b.ID ID_NEW 
from rn a
join rn b
on a.RN  = b.RN_NEW;

        ID     ID_NEW
---------- ----------
      1001       1004 
      1002       1001 
      1004       1005 
      1005       1002
```

The query defines two `row_number` sequences, first in the order of the `PK`, second in random order. The final join gets the original and new (permutated) `ID`s.

Now to *permute* a selected colums is as easy as to join your table twice with the *permutation* table in between and choose *preserved* columns from the first table, the *permuted* columns from the second one.

```
select a.ID, a.code, b.name 
from student a
join PERM p on a.id = p.id
join student b on p.id_new = b.id
order by a.id;

        ID CODE NAME 
---------- ---- ------
      1001 A    QUERTY 
      1002 B    XYZ    
      1004 C    FOO    
      1005 A    123
```

As far as you preserv the *permutation table* you can reconstruct the former state, if you drop it, there is no way to get the original data.